# Querying and Fetching db results from within a bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to do I query  a MySQL database from a bootstrap modal, based on user selection and fetch db results in same modal without the modal closing? Here's a sample of the 2 drop-downs in my modal.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="relevance">
                <form>
                  <fieldset>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                        <select class="span6">
                            <option value="">Volume 1</option>
                            <option value="">Volume 2</option>
                        </select>


                        <select class="span6">
                            <option value="">Number 1</option>
                            <option value="">Number 2</option>
                            <option value="">Number 3</option>
                            <option value="">Number 4</option>
                            <option value="">Number 5</option>
                            <option value="">Number 6</option>
                            <option value="">Number 7</option>
                            <option value="">Number 8</option>

                        </select>
                    </div><br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Sort</button>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
```

When the user clicks the search button it should query and display results without the modal closing. I can handle the php and SQL statements, i just don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AJAX call to submit form to back end to fetch the data.
Add id to your button to identify it easily

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="filter">Sort</button>`

And in javascript use jQuery to create AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#filter').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = 'path/to/php/script';
    var filterData = {}; //values you need to submit from the filter form
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: filterData,
      success: function(data) {
        // use data fetched to write it inside the DOM
      }
    });
  });
});
```